# Weird focuss loss in browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS **fully updated** and am having a problem with browsers (Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) and Firefox V43.0... Chromium does not have this problem)

Here is how to duplicate:

1. when opening new page and scrolling to the bottom, after 2-3 seconds, it scrolls back up without asking
2. when opening a form and clicking into a cell to type... still after 2-3 seconds, the focus is lost and I need to reclick as if I had never clicked in the 1st place.

On Firefox, installed extensions are AdBlock plus, Firebug, web developper and Ubuntu Modifications. On Chrome, Google docs, sheets, slides and docs offline connetion.

Has anyone had this annoyance?

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Best regards.

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour has been proven to be web application dependant. Upgrading the source code of Zabbix from alpha4 to RC1 has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I has exactly the same trouble and the solution was opening the keyboard option in the corner up right of the desktop and open the configuration.

Inside the window in the right-down corner (orange option) keyboard configuration modify the option close session in system menu.